# Define WCF Service to Get JSON Data

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I want my WCF service to return json.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (VB.NET/ASP.NET 4.6.1)

In My aspx page (located on a folder called DataUnit) i try to call my WCF service located (at the moment) on the same folder of aspx page.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Service.svc/GetCustomers',
        data: '{"MyDate": "' + dateval + '"}',......
```

But i receive Error 404

If i visualize Service.svc in Browser (http://localhost:64367/DataUnit/Service.svc) i receive message

Service Created

To Test Service.....

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:64367/DataUnit/Service.svc?wsdl
```

I've also activated in Panel Control
Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation
Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation

I've passed all day to resolve but i'm getting crazy.

**This is my code**

web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="MyNameSpace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyNameSpace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Service.svc

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

<ServiceContract()>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Service
    <OperationContract()>
    <System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", _
            ResponseFormat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function GetCustomers(ByVal MyDate As String) As String
        Try
            Dim gd As New GetOracleData
            Dim b As String = Chr(34)
            Dim newdataset As DataSet
            Dim RAPPID As String = "01"

            newdataset = gd.GetMyData(MyDate , RAPPID)
            Dim json2 As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newdataset, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

            Return json2
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

**SVC Markup:**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="MyNameSpace.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.vb" %>
```

**RouteConfig.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing

Public Module RouteConfig
    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

        routes.MapRoute(
            name := "Default",
            url := "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults := New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```

**UPDATE**

I believe that problem is on this but i don't know why and how i must implement a controller for a simple ASPX page.

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetCustomers&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   in System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   in System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   in System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   in System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   in System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro,
We need to add the WebHttp endpoint behavior to the service endpoint. Like below.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebApplication1.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="WebApplication1.CostService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication1.CostServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.CostService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

For details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/webhttp
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks Bro, Added <webHttp /> but same result Error 404.

Comment: Http 404 error mainly indicates that the file is not found. please pay attention the service address. In order to test, you could type the service address in the browser address bar to access the service by decorating the method with [WebGet]

Comment: Please use the absolute service address in the Ajax request. like below. "~/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetCustomers".

Comment: If i use  "~/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetCustomers" always Error 404 but with Firefox inspector i can see URL Requested is http://localhost:64367/DataUnit/~/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetCustomers. Very strange.

Comment: Try to use the replace the address with the practical path. If we use the right address, Can we see the request information and response error?

Comment: I suggest you add an HTTPGET method without a parameter so that we could directly test it by using the browser address bar.

Comment: Inside inspector i replace requested url with exact URL but Error 404 persists.

Comment: added this -- <OperationContract()> _
    <System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", _
            ResponseFormat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function GetText(ByVal MyDate As String) As String
        Dim Test As String = "{'350.200 BBB':[{'name':'arold','surname':'winter'},{'name':'Rinald','surname':'Miki'}]},{'name':'Rudolf','surname':'Mann'}]}"
        Return Test
    End Function------ Then in address bar i put "http://localhost:64367/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetText?MyDate=01-08-2019" but "HTTP 404 Impossibile find resource"

Comment: Added an HTTPGET method without a parameter but Error 404. In Visual Studio 2013 tried to add (under References) a Reference To Service and after press Discover i can see the Service "http://localhost:64367/DataUnit/Service.svc" with 2 methods "GetCustomers" and "GetText".

Comment: I believe the problem is on [HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/DataUnit/Service.svc/GetCustomers&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.   in System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   in System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
** I've updated original post

Comment: If your project is asp.net webform, please do not add the MVC routing table to the current project. 
In addition, if we add an HttpGet method without parameters, can we access the method directly through the browser address bar while debugging(we should ensure that the project is running while debugging)?